# .Net 6 Api Generic query sorting based on columnName type and order Asc Desc

Tags: c#, .net, api, entity-framework-core, iqueryable

I'm trying to gain some experience with .net 6 apis and I have designed a simple app in which the user can sort the data based on a specific column like name or created.
But now I also want to sort based on a status that can be active or inactive (stored in DB stored as a bool).

So, I would like, if possible, to have a generic method to apply sorting also by including boolean conditions like:

```
query = query.OrderBy(u=> u.status==false/true)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is sorting by `false/true` any different than the other sorts you've done? You should just be able to sort by status the way you sort any other column.

Comment: If you are looking to sort on more than one field then you can use the `ThenBy` and apply `Where` for your condition: `query.Where(u=>u.status == false/true).OrderBy(u => u.name).ThenBy(u => u.status)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OrderBy` already does that for you.
In case you want to order by `false` just write the following:

```
query = query.OrderBy(u => u.status)
```

This will bring the items with status `false` to the front, and move the ones with `true` to the end.

In case you want to do the opposite and bring the `true`-s to the front, use `OrderByDescending`

```
query = query.OrderByDescending(u => u.status)
```